# How to log in whilst offline in firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have enabledPersistence() as indicated in the documentation on my app.ts.

```
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
 imports: [ AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence()]
```

Once i login and disconnect my network the application works well in offline mode and it uodates when network is reconnected.

My login function is:

```
  async login() {
          await this.presentLoadings();
            const { email, password } = this
            try { 

              const res = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email , password)

              if(res.user) {
                this.user.setUser({
                  email,
                  password,
                  uid: res.user.uid
                })
                this.router.navigate(['/tabs/dashboard'])
              }

            } catch(err) {
              this.presentToast(err.message);
            }
            finally
            {
              this.loading.dismiss();
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to sign in a new user without an internet connection.

That said, if the user was signed in before, Firebase Authentication will restore their authentication state automatically when the app is restarted, and that *will* work when there is no network connection.

To detect this automatic sign-in, [use an `onAuthStateChange` listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, so set the state, and navigate to the dashboard.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much